# Is this scene in the Mandalorian a Mad Max homage?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian, boba-fett, mad-max

One scene in *The Mandalorian* bears a striking resemblance to the end of *Mad Max: Beyond Thunderdome*. Note the desert landscape, sunset, back to the audience, long robes, and long, angled weapons.

[image]

[image]

Have any creators stated if it was an intentional homage?

Comment: Sergio Leone homage more like

Answer (score 4):

A shadowy silhouette in front of a sunset is a motif which is so common that it can hardly be considered a reference.

If this shot references another work, then it's more likely a reference to a shot from *Star Wars: A New Hope* which takes place on the same planet showing the same two suns setting:

[image: Star Wars IV 0:25:45]